# Volley not properly executing node.js POST request

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

I am creating an app with node.js as the backend scripting language. In order to test my app, I created a simple node.js script with the following code

```
  app.post('/hello', function(request, response){
  var outputJson = request.param('test');
  var myJson = "{'Value':"+outputJson+"}";
  response.send(JSON.stringify(outputJson));
  })
```

I am calling this script from my app using `Volley`. The code is as follows

```
  private void sendDatatoHeroku(final String names){
  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sending Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  StringRequest str = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }){
  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
  params.put("test",names);
  return params;
  }
  };
  RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
  rq.add(str);
  }
```

The JSON toast always shows null. I also tried to call the URL with RESTClient and I was getting null too. I have called PHP scripts with POST method in the same manner and it worked everytime. 
The end point of the node.js script is `https://sfbpush.herokuapp.com/hello`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: u might review the 'json' your actually sending (server-side), log it and verify for valid json object.

Comment: sending from the android or the node.js @RobertRowntree

Comment: I actually test my end points here : chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html..It always gives me undefined unless I put the content in the URL,,But this a POST request..How can that be possible I have no idea @RobertRowntree